# Filling dynamic values inside array after a certain word

Tags: c, arrays, client-server, arguments

What I am trying to do is to put the data inside an char array called “msg” but before that I want to include any word, i.e. "DATA" in order to distinguish between the coming data, before sending the msg from the client code to the server code. So it will be something like this:

```
D   A   T   A   ‘\0’    i   j
```

I did the following in the client.c code :

```
char msg[10]= "DATA'\0' ";
printf(" the msg %s\n",msg);

for(int i=0;i<layers;i++) // loop for the number of layers
for(int j=0;j<packetsPerLayer;j++) // loop for the number of packets in each layer
{ 
    sprintf( FunctionToStartFillingAtIndex4(msg)," %d %d", i,j);
            printf("%s",msg);
    //here will be the sendto function which will send the msg containing the word “DATA”
     sendto();
}
```

I am done with sending and receiving connection part between the client and server code. However, my problem is that I don’t know how to fill in the array with indexes after the word “DATA”, I don’t know if there is a certain way that can help me doing this. Briefly, how to tell the array to fill the  i and  j inside index [5] and index [6] after the word “DATA”.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using C programming language

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are actually using C (as there is no C++ in your example code) and that there is enough space in `msg` to contain your complete message (and I doubt seriously that 10 bytes would be enough for everything), you could do something like this:

```
char msg[50] = "";
int index = 0;
printf(" the msg %s\n", msg);
for(int i=0; i<layers; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<packetsPerLayer; j++)
    {
        index += snprintf(&(msg[index]), 50 - index, " DATA");
        //add i to the message and store how many characters it took up
        index += snprintf(&(msg[index]), 50 - index, " %d", i);
        //add j to the message
        index += snprintf( &(msg[index]), 50 - index, " %d", j);
        printf("%s", msg);
        //do sendto()
    }
}
```

I'd strongly recommend using `snpritnf` over `sprintf` to avoid accidentally overrunning your ouput buffer.

Also keep in mind that `i` and `j` will almost always occupy more than one byte each when converted to string representations (unless you are absolutely certain that they will never be negative or greater than nine).

**Edit**: I've changed the code to reflect your comment. There will be an extra space (`' '`) before the first `'D'` in the string, but you could easily just provide `&(msg[1])` as the buffer argument to `sendto` rather than `msg` to accommodate this. Again, you need to make sure your buffer is large enough to hold your complete message.

Comment: Yes, you all right. But when I run the code in order to understand it, the result is the whole array with 50 bytes is getting filled but what I need to do will be something like this : DATA00 DATA 01 DATA02 DATA03 then it will start with the second layer DATA 10 DATA 12 DATA13 and so on ..

Comment: You should edit your question to include this information. Also consider adding an example of correct output to make it clearer.